# Selenium and Chromedriver - Can't click element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an element on a website using selenium and Chromedriver. For other elements I have been able to click on by using their Relative Xpath. However, when I try to copy the xpath of the new element it copies the Absolute Xpath which gives me an error.

The section I am trying to access is:

```
<div class="tile transferMarketTile">
  <div class="loadingSpinner"></div>
  <header>
    <h1 class="tileHeader">Search the Transfer Market</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="tileContent"></div>
  <div class="tileDisabled" style="display: none;">
    <div class="textField tileDisabledMessage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have tried clicking the element using:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/article/div[1]/div[2]"));
        transfers.click();
```

I am have using the relative xpath that I found using a Chrome extension and this did not work either.

I was wondering if there is a way around this. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Which element you are trying to click?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear! It is 'Search the transfer Market'

Comment: Okay. Whether "Search the transfer Market " is clickable in UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the web Element in the below ways,

You can select the Unique Parent Tag first and then directly access the required tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'transferMarketTile')]/.//h1")).click();
```

If the visible Text is Unique in the Page, then you can use with the
    text() option in Xpath

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Search the Transfer Market']")).click();
```

Comment: I tried entering the code suggested and I recieve this error message: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class,'transferMarketTile')]/.//h1"}

Comment: I also tried the other line and got a similar error

Comment: Whether this element is available inside the frame?

Comment: Im sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Although you can click on the element manually if that answers your question.

Comment: Inspect the above particular Element and then search with iframe in the element page. If there is any iframe found, then check whether it is the parent tag of your required element tag. If there is no iframe tag found, then need to add some explicit wait before performing this action.

Comment: Thank you I added a thead.sleep(2000) and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: Generally ,Thread Sleep can be avoided and you can use explicit wait and it will work perfectly. Below explicit wait can be added before performing action,  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("<<XPath>>")));